# Why WordPress login_redirect is not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I'm trying to redirect users after login, but common solution with 'login_redirect' filter do not work at all, even with simple variant when trying to redirect to google.

What I do:
Add this to functions.php:

```
function login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ){
    return 'https://google.com';
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Try to login as a test "Subscriber" user, and get landed at "/wp-admin/profile.php" page after login.

What I'm doing wrong? Please help.

P.S.: All plugins was deactivated when I test this.

Comment: Same in my case. Did you find any solution?